# What's wrong with this include statement?

Tags: php, wordpress, include

This function is returning the content of the file rather the result of `fetch_link_settings_overide()` within it.

The issue is not with the overide function as after the initial error I commented out my modification just to be sure it wasn't something I had done there.

```
function fetch_link_settings(){
    include( plugins_url()."/plugin-child/plugin_overrides.php");
    return fetch_link_settings_override();
}
```

Adding the  content of the derived function plugin-child/plugin_overrides.php as we are not getting anywhere currently.

```
function fetch_link_settings_override(){

    global $post;

    // If the destination url is set by the user, use that.  Otherwise, use the permalink

    $destination_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_promo_slider_url', true);

    // ASAdd additional place to look in the case of the post being via the PODS advert track
    if( ! $destination_url )
            $destination_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'okd_advert_link', true); 

    if( ! $destination_url )

        $destination_url = get_permalink($post->ID);

    // If the target attribute is set by the user, use that.  Otherwise, set it to _self

    $target = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_promo_slider_target', true);

    if( ! $target ) $target = '_self';

    // Setup the disable links variable

    $disable_links = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_promo_slider_disable_links', true);

    return compact('destination_url', 'target', 'disable_links');

}
```

Comment: What does `plugins_url()`return? It should not be a url but a path on the local file-sytem.

Comment: See [`plugins_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) vs. [`plugin_dir_path`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path).

Comment: @jeroen The $plugins_url variable will equal to the absolute URL to the plugins directory, e.g. "http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins"
If i use plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) it returns /public_html/example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin-child
giving....Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch_link_settings_overide()

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook So remove `/plugin-child` from your string (it's already returned from the function according to your previous comment) and use `require` to make sure the file is included.

Comment: @jeroen sorry mate for the delay, typo and assumption.
Resolving the assumption I should have said: If i use plugin_dir_path( FILE ) it returns '/home4/public_html/example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin-original'

That is: plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'plugin-child/plugin_overrides.php' returns and concats to: '/home4/example.com/public_html/domain/wp-content/plugins/plugin-original/plugin-child/plugin_overrides.php'

This isnt right as both plugin-original and plugin-child are peers below the plugins directory.

Comment: I get: failed to open stream: No such file or directory unless I use either the original call I made or the a a fully typed address: i.e.  'wp-content/plugins/plugin-original/plugin‌​-child/plugin_overrides.php' but with the output issue.

I perhaps should further that the modification I wanted to include via the override - works perfectly ok if actually code in the plugin-original/plugin_overrides.php. This started as an exercise to try and avoid mods being overwritten in the event of plugin upgrade. As it would be quick to add the include and derived function. Only a small effort required.

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook If they are peers, you could use `plugin_dir_path() . '/../plugin-child/plugin_overrides.php'` (not sure about the slash at the start of the string, that depends on the function output).

Comment: @jeroen indeed that gets to the correct file (without foward-slash)but the output is exactly the same as I was experiencing - php file content. I shall add the file content of the override above though I fail to understand how that should make a difference.

Comment: You need to specify exactly what is happening and at what line. The include should not output anything, the function returns something and echoes something.

Comment: What are you talking about there are only two lines. The override function is irrelevant I have included it for posterity. To illustrate that there is nothing weird going on there. This line in the original function returns exactly the same as the code prior to move to the override: return fetch_link_settings_override(); returns an exact copy of what it would if the code was in the original function, the only exception is that mod potentially picks up an alternative url. The only echo in there was there for debugging purposes. It does not alter the function or the problem. I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You write this:

```
include( plugins_url()."/plugin-child/plugin_overides.php");
```

Why is [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) there? The [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function is strictly based on the file system:

```
The `include` statement includes and evaluates the specified file.
```

As explained in the WordPress docs, the `plugins_url()` would give you the full web URL which is 100% different than the file system WordPress is installed on:

> Retrieves the absolute URL to the plugins directory (without the
>   trailing slash) or, when using the $path argument, to a specific file
>   under that directory.

So perhaps it should be like this:

```
include("/plugin-child/plugin_overides.php");
```

Or perhaps you need the [`plugin_dir_path()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path)?

```
include(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "/plugin-child/plugin_overides.php");
```

But that seems wrong. Where would `/plugin-child/plugin_overides.php`? Try doing this:

```
include("/full/path/to/wordpress/and/this/plugin-child/plugin_overides.php");
```

Just replace `/full/path/to/wordpress/and/this/` with the actual file system path to `/plugin-child/plugin_overides.php`.

**EDIT:** Since the original poster is persistent in using `plugins_url()` despite all of the suggestions otherwise, here is my detailed response:

> …you said “you cannot load raw functions via a URL with include” well
>   this is not relevant because even if I add $some_var = 'smith'; as the
>   first statement in the included file, it is not visible in the
>   function using the include.

Apologies. Functions, classes, strings, constants… Just about anything that you want to be raw, unprocessed PHP will simply not be passed via an `http://` or `https://` URL because Apache will parse the PHP instructions & simply return the *output* of that file and not the raw, unprocessed *contents* of the PHP in that file.

Additionally the original poster contents the following:

> You can’t help me because what you are saying does not make sense or
>   you are not explaining yourself adequately. Look at these examples:
>
> ```
> include realpath(dirname(FILE) . "/" . "relative_path");
> include("data://text/plain;base64,".base64_encode($content));
> include("data://text/plain,".urlencode($content));
> ```
>
> All taken from [the official PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). They all use
>   functions returning components that are concatenated with the rest of
>   the url. I also tried this typing the filepath explicitly and the
>   result is the same.

The examples cited are as follows:

```
include realpath(dirname(FILE) . "/" . "relative_path");
```

This is a filesystem level include which is the most common way PHP files are included into other files.

```
include("data://text/plain;base64,".base64_encode($content));
include("data://text/plain,".urlencode($content));
```

These are both `data` URLs. Not `http` or `https`.  So again when you use `plugins_url()` what you are getting is a full `http://` or `https://` URL in which Apache parses the PHP instructions & simply return the *output* of that file and not the raw, unprocessed *contents* of the PHP in that file.  Or as very clearly explained [in the PHP documentation you are linking to](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php); emphasis mine:

> If "URL include wrappers" are enabled in PHP, you can specify the file
>   to be included using a URL (via HTTP or other supported wrapper - see
>   Supported Protocols and Wrappers for a list of protocols) instead of a
>   local pathname. If the target server interprets the target file as PHP
>   code, variables may be passed to the included file using a URL request
>   string as used with HTTP GET. **This is not strictly speaking the same
>   thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's
>   variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server
>   and the result is then being included into the local script.**

Going back to your example, you say now the contents of `plugin_overides.php` is `$some_var = 'smith';`. How exactly?  If it is a PHP file like this:

```
<?php
  $some_var = 'smith';
?>
```

When you call that file via a URL generated by the following code:

```
include(plugins_url() . "/plugin-child/plugin_overrides.php");
```

Assuming your website is `http://some.cool.website/` the you are basically making a call like this:

```
http://some.cool.website/plugin-child/plugin_overides.php
```

So the output of `plugin_overides.php` would be 100% blank.  If you wanted to get output of that file, you could do the following:

```
<?php
  $some_var = 'smith';
  echo $some_var;
?>
```

And that would return `smith`. Meaning the absolute ONLY output you would get from that call is pure text. Nothing else.

Now I see you actually have posted the contents of `plugin_overides.php`. My example explanation above is still apt, but still a basic question. This is your function; just the interface & `return` for example:

```
function fetch_link_settings_override(){

    // Other code removed. Just a structural illustration for now.
    return compact('destination_url', 'target', 'disable_links');

}
```

Do you actually call `fetch_link_settings_override()` in `plugin_overides.php` when it runs? Well, if that function does not run, then there is 100% no way you will ever get any output. But assuming good faith, look at your `return` statement here:

```
return compact('destination_url', 'target', 'disable_links');
```

If you are returning `compact`, then you are returning an array. You cannot simply return a bare array as a URL call like this `http://some.cool.website/plugin-child/plugin_overides.php`.  The output at most would be simply the word `Array`.

If the goal is to take that array & do something, then you should use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in `fetch_link_settings_override` and then use [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the receiving side of that. So the `return` statement would be something like this:

```
return json_encode(compact('destination_url', 'target', 'disable_links'));
```

Comment: `plugins_url()` may be returning an additional string as part of the file path. Possibly like a configuration file. Although I will admit, if this is the case, the naming of the function is a little poor.

Comment: @JakeGould All these
include(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "/plugin-child/plugin_overides.php");
include("/plugin-child/plugin_overides.php");
include( "http://okdja.com/wp-content/plugins"."/plugin-child/plugin_overides.php");

Give  ... Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch_link_settings_overide()

Comment: @War10ck Surely if plugins_url were returning something other than expected it would not be able to include the content of the file. As it would presumably not recognize the compound url

Comment: What I have is a situation where: 
plugins/plugin_in_question has certain functions overidden in
plugins/plugin_in_question-child

Comment: @JakeGould why would using include_once do anything other than what include does. As far as I was aware its sole purpose is to insure that there are not multiple declaration with the same function name. No?

And why is plugins_url() just plain wrong. Take a look here http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php 

Example 3 for posterity:
// Works.
include "http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2";
You need to see the example it includes the protocol, but I dont know how to preserve the text in here.

Comment: @JakeGould I am aware of the difference between the two statements. Thanks for the advice. I have been using PHP on and off since about the year 2000 - 2003, though clearly it's not my main focus or I would not need to ask why the include is failing to return the value expected. However if you think that the use of one or the other was going to provide a solution to this problem perhaps I should be giving you some tips. :)

Comment: @JakeGould Regarding your third suggestion it returns the expected error 'failed to open stream: No such file or directory'

You have not said why plugins_url() is plain wrong. It is a function that returns a string url. And as the example I pointed to clearly shows include expects a string url. Further more using a function or variable to provide the string is legitimate - see that same page for many examples.

Comment: ....you said "you cannot load raw functions via a URL with include" well this is not relevant because even if I add $some_var = 'smith'; as the first statement in the included file, it is not visible in the function using the include.

Comment: @JakeGould Well thanks for taking the time to explain things. The edit  has turned your response into a bible. :) Will go through it properly later. Appreciate the effort.