# Securing third-party API credentials in PHP and include

Tags: php, api, security, curl, include

I am writing a series of functions to interact with third-party APIs that will be included in other PHP scripts. Most of these third-party APIs use token-based authentication, so I would like to store these tokens within the function, but I’m wondering what the best practices are for preventing exploitation of those functions in the included file.

For example, in a script called `~/public_html/includes/functions.php` I would define some functions that call a public API using cURL, and then return some sort of response from the API. Then, within my app, I would include `~/public_html/includes/functions.php` and call the functions to interact with the third-party APIs.

My concern is what if someone else includes `http://www.example.com/includes/functions.php` in their script, and starts calling my functions to make API calls using my credentials? Should functions.php live somewhere else, perhaps outside of the `~/public_html` dir? Or perhaps I can use UNIX permissions to prevent anyone but my own apps to include the `functions.php` script?

Comment: @JakeGould - It is possible to include a URL via http, for example if you add `include("http://www.cnn.com/")` to a PHP script it will display cnn.com's output on the page. I guess what I'm wondering if it's possible to call functions included in that script over http or if it simply echoes the output of the script, which would theoretically be nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My concern is what if someone else includes
>   http://www.example.com/includes/functions.php in their script, and
>   starts calling my functions to make API calls using my credentials?
>   Should functions.php live somewhere else, perhaps outside of the
>   ~/public_html dir? Or perhaps I can use UNIX permissions to prevent
>   anyone but my own apps to include the functions.php script?

You are mixing up a lot of things here. And the long story short: You should not worry. I gave a full explanation on how include works with URLs [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618933/whats-wrong-with-this-include-statement/23618966#23618966). Below is a summary for your purposes.

Specifically, while one could use `include` to include full URLs like `include('http://www.google.com/');` the only thing you get from that `include` is the final rendered content of the page. 100% none of the functions, classes, variables, strings, constants or anything contained in the internals of that PHP code. Or as very clearly explained [in the PHP documentation you are linking to](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php); emphasis mine:

> If "URL include wrappers" are enabled in PHP, you can specify the file
>   to be included using a URL (via HTTP or other supported wrapper - see
>   Supported Protocols and Wrappers for a list of protocols) instead of a
>   local pathname. If the target server interprets the target file as PHP
>   code, variables may be passed to the included file using a URL request
>   string as used with HTTP GET. **This is not strictly speaking the same
>   thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's
>   variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server
>   and the result is then being included into the local script.**

So you cannot include credentials remotely—or any PHP internals—in the way you describe. The only way that could happen is if `~/public_html/includes/functions.php` were included locally. That is when PHP internals are exposed.

Or the better way to understand this: When you request a PHP file via `http://` or `https://` it is parsed & processed via the PHP module in Apache. So it only returns the final product—if any—post often conveyed by an `echo` statement.

But when you include a file via the local file system it is *not* parsed by the PHP module in Apache. It is simply raw code.  And that is how you can use the functions, classes, variables, strings, constants and anything contained in the internals of that PHP code.

Comment: Very clear explanation. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't leaving anything open to possible exploitation. It makes sense that if someone were to include the functions.php script over HTTP it would just display the rendered output. Thanks again!